# ListBox with hover effect, space between items and no padding

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, hover

Currently I have this visual :

[image]

I want to have an hover effect which match my border and have a space between items.

```
  <ListBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5,0,0,0"  Grid.RowSpan="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding Programme.Versions, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MouseLeftButtonUp="ChangerVersion_MouseLeftButtonUp" Style="{StaticResource NoBorder}">
        <!--<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Vertical"  />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel> -->
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle >
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>-->
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="bOs:VersionBO" >
                <Border Padding="0" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource Accent}" >
                    <Grid Cursor="Hand">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="7"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Fill="{DynamicResource Accent}" />
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="{DynamicResource Accent}"  Foreground="White" Margin="5"  FontSize="18">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}V{0}.{1}">
                                    <Binding Path="Numero" />
                                    <Binding Path="NumeroModification" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"  />
                        <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Width="20" Margin="0,2,2,0"  Visibility="{Binding Interdit, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Source="../Images/Icones/interdit.png" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                        <TextBlock  Grid.Column="2"  Grid.Row="1">
                            <TextBlock.Text>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValuesWithSeparatorConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="Langue.Libelle" />
                                    <Binding Path="SousTitre" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </TextBlock.Text>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

When I redefine the `ItemContainerStyle`, I lose the hover effect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some custom themes? If so, there should be a default `ListBoxItemStyle` resource somewhere in your application.

Then your solution is easy:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,2"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

If not, getting the default style will be slightly harder. I suggest to use Blend. There you can right click your listbox in the designer and select to edit the template: Remember to first **remove the ItemContainerStyle** from your listbox.

[image]

This will create a new static resource where you can base your template on.

Comment: I have tried the 'Blend thing": I have extract the default template then I have bind the "ItemContainerStyle" with this default style but the hover effect has disappeared and the width of item is no constant anymore